@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function on a Text content
I'm trying to create a advance amount tracking app but in this one particular file at the last composable function it is showing the error @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function im tried many ways but it doesn't work...anyone help to solve this....
package com.example.advance

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.advance.ui.theme.AdvanceTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AdvanceTheme {
                MainScreen { contractType ->
                    navigateToWorkerList(contractType)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun navigateToWorkerList(contractType: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, WorkerListActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("CONTRACT_TYPE", contractType)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(navigateToWorkerList: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xFFE3F2FD))
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Select Contract",
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color(0xFF1976D2),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 24.dp)
        )

        ContractButton("Sarvanan Contract", navigateToWorkerList)
        ContractButton("Janaki Contract", navigateToWorkerList)
        ContractButton("Lumpsum Workers", navigateToWorkerList)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ContractButton(contractName: String, navigateToWorkerList: (String) -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = { navigateToWorkerList(contractName) },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color(0xFF42A5F5)),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = contractName, fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color.White)
    }
}


i'm tried to removing the composable annnotations at the last block of code any many ways but it doesn't work
